# IE6 Hacks: Getting jQuery tools expose to work properly on my site

Tags: jquery, css, javascript, internet-explorer-6

I am trying to get the jQuery tools 'expose' function to work properly in IE6. The page is http://204.51.246.10:12123/test-ie6.aspx

You will need IE6 to reproduce the bug (obviously :)). If you click 'Sign In' on the top-right corner (below the 'Join Today!' button), you will notice that the sign in panel (fieldset#login-controls) is shown improperly (compare with FF or Chrome).

This appears to be because div#header is non-static - not sure why. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Cheers,
Wild Thing

Answer (score 0):

Take the #UserLogin_SigninPanel out of the TABLE#UserLogin

If possible, place it somewhere closer to the end of BODY

You are trying to show a DIV that is nested within a TABLE, and IE6 does not like that very much.

Comment: Thanks! Will try this out shortly...problem is that the inbuilt login control generates the table. 

I might stick to the workaround of redirecting users to a login page, cause IE6 honestly isn't worth the trouble. 

Thanks anyways!